# Loading obj files in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, wavefront

I'm new to OpenGL and I'm trying to load obj files into my code. I have a code of a simple animating cube. When I declare the vertices and indices as follows it works properly:

```
GLfloat cube_vertices[] = {
// front
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    // back
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
};
GLushort cube_elements[] = {
    // front
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    // top
    1, 5, 6,
    6, 2, 1,
    // back
    7, 6, 5,
    5, 4, 7,
    // bottom
    4, 0, 3,
    3, 7, 4,
    // left
    4, 5, 1,
    1, 0, 4,
    // right
    3, 2, 6,
    6, 7, 3,
};
```

However, when I'm trying to get similar number from a file, the program runs without error but shows nothing in the window. Here is my code for loading the obj file:

```
vector<GLfloat> vertices;
vector<GLushort> elements;

ifstream in("cube.obj", ios::in);
if (!in)
{
    cerr << "Cannot open " << "sample.obj" << endl; exit(1);
}

string line;
while (getline(in, line))
{
    if (line.substr(0, 2) == "v ")
    {
        istringstream s(line.substr(2));
        GLfloat v;
        s >> v; vertices.push_back(v);
        s >> v; vertices.push_back(v);
        s >> v; vertices.push_back(v);

    }
    else if (line.substr(0, 2) == "f ")
    {
        istringstream s(line.substr(2));
        GLushort a, b, c;
        s >> a; s >> b; s >> c;
        elements.push_back(a); elements.push_back(b); elements.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

The cube.obj file is saved as follows:

```
o cube
v -1.0 -1.0 1.0
v 1.0 -1.0 1.0
v 1.0 1.0 1.0
v -1.0 1.0 1.0
v -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
v 1.0 -1.0 -1.0
v 1.0 1.0 -1.0
v -1.0 1.0 -1.0
f 0 1 2
f 2 3 0
f 1 5 6
f 6 2 1
f 7 6 5
f 5 4 7
f 4 0 3
f 3 7 4
f 4 5 1
f 1 0 4
f 3 2 6
f 6 7 3
```

I'm just getting a blank window in the output. Do you have any idea why the loader doesn't work?

I upload the data thus

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), &elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

When I don't put the `&` operator before `vertices` and `elements` it gives compilation error of "no suitable conversion".

Comment: The loading code seems fine. How do you upload the data from the vector into the video memory?

Comment: glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); and  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), &elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
When I don't put the & operator before "vertices" and "elements" it gives compilation error of "no suitable conversion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`glBufferData` expects the raw data and not the vector directly, also the size of this data should be given correctly. What you are doing here is passing the size of the `vector` itself and not the data it contains.

A `vector` is a data structure, a container, with metadata like a pointer to the data it's going to hold and a variable to hold the count of element it holds. When you do `sizeof(vector)` it would always return a constant number, irrespective of the number of elements it houses; this size is the `sizeof(pointer-to-data) + sizeof(variable-holding-count)`. This data is not what you want.

Also, when you pass `&vertices`, you are passing the address of the vector itself and not the address of the data it contains. [`vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) gives the address of the data contained inside it.

Instead do this:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat),
             vertices.data(),
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

should do it. The same goes for element array buffer too.

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             elements.size() * sizeof(GLushort),
             elements.data(),
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

[`vector::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) gives the count of the elements it contains, that times the size of one element gives the right size of the data contained.

#### Aside

```
line.substr(0, 2) == "v "
line.substr(0, 2) == "f "
```

This would create two substrings unnecessarily, instead you could do this to check the same thing

```
line[0] == 'v'
line[0] == 'f'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a million! I am not clear with "raw data" that you have mentioned. So, considering a vector and an array from the same type with equal entities, vector[i] == array[i] will be FALSE?

Comment: By _raw data_, I meant just the data of the model and not more or less. A vector usually, internally just has a pointer and a size variable. It's this pointer that points to the data that you insert into it via `push_back`. `v[i] == a[i]` is true, but that doesn't mean arrays and vectors are the same.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks again!

Comment: A minor optimisation is possible in the code, I've put it under the Aside heading. I've added links to the functions used; I'd suggest you to look at them and get into the habit of reading documentation so that you've more clarity when you code things up. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted loads in the vertices and faces just fine, so you will need to post your rendering code in order to get a specific answer.

From what you have posted though, I have a few suggestions:

- You've used cube_vertices and cube_elements when specifying the cube, but different variables when loading from a file. Are you trying to render from the empty arrays in your program?

Comment: On the contrary, the destructor of `ifstream` would automatically call `close`, so [it's recommended](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/close) that it's not called explicitly.

Comment: I was not aware, thanks for the tip. Edited to reflect this.